# TypeError: _config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

firebase.js :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth"
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "rxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxxx"
  storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxx"
};

let app;
if(!app){
  app=initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  console.log("App initialized");
}
else{
  console.log("Firebase already initialized\n");
}
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
if (auth){
  console.log("Auth working");
}
export {auth, db, storage};
```

register.js

```
import {auth,db } from "../config/firebase";

function emailRegister({ email, password }) {
  console.log(email);
  console.log(password);
  return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
}

export { emailRegister};
```

Error:

Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: *config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

This err

How to solve this error

Comment: It's solved using new some previous questions.